# Debugging ArcPy script to search, get value, compare to field names and sum field values?

Tags: arcpy

`I am looking to do the following task:

- Look at the values in RegID_6k99 field (numerical field).
- Select all records where "RegID_6k99 == 0". In this case 6 records should be selected.
- For each of the selected records look at the FLABEL field value (String) for each record (6 different FLABELs).
- Look at the field names of the feature class (fieldlist).
- If any of the field names are equal to the value (string) of the FLABELs then sum the value (numerical) for each of the fields for that row. In this case for one row 6 fields have the same string as the FLABEL so for this row the six values will be summed into the new field (RegIntFlows) for that row.

In this case 6 rows will have a RegIntFlows field value.

- Then increment for "RegID_6k99 == 1" and so on until the maximum RegID_6k99 value. All records should have a RegIntFlows value.

I have written some code but it doesn't run and needs modification.

Attached is screendump of feature class and current script.

```
import arcpy
fieldlist = arcpy.ListFields("C:/Temp/NIData.gdb/fc_f6000_in99Matx") #create list of fields
fc = "C:/Temp/NIData.gdb/fc_f6000_in99Matx" #reference feature class
result = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("RegID_6k99"))] #search field
unique = set(result)
lengthDict = {}
for uni in unique:
    where = "\"RegID_6k99\" = '%s'" % (uni)
    lengths = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("FLABEL"), where)]
    for field in fieldlist:
        if field.name.lower() == lengths: #if field name is equal to FLABEL value    
            lengthDict[uni] = sum(lengths)
            for each in lengthDict.keys():
                print "%s: %s" % (each, lengthDict[each])
                else #not sure how to finish

import arcpy
> fieldlist = arcpy.ListFields("C:/Temp/NIData.gdb/fc_f6000_in99Matx")
> fc = "C:/Temp/NIData.gdb/fc_f6000_in99Matx"
> rfield = "RegID_6k99"
> nfield = "FLABEL"
> # create an expression with proper delimiters
> expression = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, rfield) + "=2"
> # create a search cursor with list comprehension to return a unique set of values based on sql expression
> values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (rfield, nfield), where_clause=expression)]
> uniqueValues = set(values)
> list = []
> # check if FLABEL value equals field name
> for field in fieldlist:
    if field.name.lower() == values:
        list.append(field)
        RowRegFlows = sum(list)
        row.UpdateRow(row)


>>> ## Attempt to sum the values of the applicable field values
```

The code works - does what I want - up until the last three lines. I have attempted to do the last part of task in the last three lines but not confident about them. There is no error message (see attached jpg). If the FLABEL value for row is equal to all of the field names then I want to sum the values into a blank field (TotRegFlows) for each row. 
Do I need an update cursor as well? Can anyone advise?
Many thanks
[image: Revised_code]

Comment: Don't just say that it doesn't work. Tell us which line is the problem, & what error you get.

Comment: Is the problem indentation? (the `else` statement needs to be at the same level as the `if` statement, not nested under `for each...`)

Comment: In your second dot point you say "In this case 6 records should be selected".  Is this happening? If not, then lets dispense with the rest of your code and focus on solving your first issue in this first question.

Comment: True, sorry very new to Python and finding it very frustrating as I know what I want to achieve but can't code it correctly.  Thanks for the comments. I went back to basics  as suggested and tried to through the code line by line to really understand the code and check if it is working. As a result I've posted a new version above. @PolyGeo

Comment: Using `list` as a variable is unwise as it is a builtin function.

Comment: Should i use numpy array instead?

Comment: you are missing a : where the red is

Comment: Thanks, the : is included in the code above. Sorry previous Screendump hadn't shown it. Issue is the part after.

Comment: @Lorraine  Please consider breaking questions such as these up into simpler parts (and single questions).  You will likely get much better answers that way.

Comment: You need an update cursor.